# Facing issue while importing maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import maven project into my workspace. I have added settings.xml in .m2 folder.
But I am getting below error while importing the project:

An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
Unable to provision, see the following errors:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *

1 error
```

Please let me know how I can resolve this.

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.8. I have copied the certificate cacerts.jks but I believe i have to enter its details while building maven project

Comment: try using below in terminal 
mvn eclipse:eclipse

and then import the project in eclipse

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this. I was able to import the project but it's not building and getting the same error under Maven Java EE Configuration Problems.

Comment: Never ever call `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. It is long deprecated.